# Expo Go app does not work on Android phones - specifically Oppo A37 series phones

Tags: react-native, expo

**Expo Go** app does not work on Android phones - specifically Oppo A37 series. I have tried to uninstall the app, reset the device and many other ways, but the Expo Go app has not been working. Who can help me with it? Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: try connecting your phone to a computer and running `adb logcat` (`adb` is in android sdk) to see if there is any useful error. if you believe is a bug please post it to https://github.com/expo/expo/issues. you can use an emulator until it's figured out. https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/